# zoom geckoFX contents in C# winforms

Tags: zooming, geckofx

I'd like to know how can I zoom in or out the contents of a geckoFX browser control without having to change css settings every time a page loads. Is there a method for that purpose? If there is no easy way to do it, then how could I send a "ctrl +" or "ctrl -" to the control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
browser.GetMarkupDocumentViewer().SetFullZoomAttribute(3.0f);
```

I just tested that with the "GeckoFXTest" sample app that is part of the GeckoFX 22 source. My test ran this when you click one of the buttons. As with most things in GeckoFX, if you try to do it before the browser is fully loaded and relaxed, and it crashes, try moving it to later in the lifecycle.

In production, I have used the following method which does use CSS, but does it in memory:

```
browser.Document.Body.Style.CssText = "-moz-transform: scale(1.5); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I've mentioned I'm not looking for a css solution.

Comment: @pzogr I'm curious, what is the specific difficulty with doing it this way? Knowing that might motivate someone to offer (or create) another solution.

Comment: First of all it won't work (I get an exception the first time it's run - I've added it to the document_completed event). And I need a solution that will work even if the webpage alters its code after this statement.

Comment: OK @pzogr, that makes sense. I've found another way and updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your advice about the implementation was crucial. It works perfectly fine